# Complexity for binary search in a non random access structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, complexity-theory, binary-search

Performing binary search on a sorted array has `O(logN)` complexity where N is the number of elements in the array.
But if we perform binary searches in a sorted (linked) list then what is the complexity?
We are doing `logN` comparisons of the middle element of the range but to get to the range the complexity is `O(N)` due to the fact that the list is not a random access structure.
So is the time complexity:
1) `logN * O(N) = O(N)` treating `logN` as a constant? or
2) `logN*O(N) = O(NlogN)` meaning that `logN = O(logN)` in all cases?

What is correct here? 1 or 2?

Comment: Why don't just iterate over entire list in `O(N)`? Performing binary search would be `O(NlogN)` because you can access elements in `O(N)`.

Comment: @fas My question is purely asymptotic analysis. It is not related to actual evaluating which data structure to use

Answer (score 0):

The second assumption is correct and first is wrong.  Asymptotic analysis deals with growth. If the number of nodes increase, log(n) would also increase. You can't treat it as a constant. For a very basic example, if you had 10 nodes and it took 10 seconds to execute, assuming 100 nodes take 200 seconds to execute seems better more accurate than assuming 100 seconds (by neglecting log(n)).

Comment: The reasoning you mention is why I got confused on this and asked it. Because on the other hand, `O(NlogN) > O(N)` but the worse case we can have in a list is going over all nodes which is `O(N)` and doing the binary search we are essentially traversing `N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 +... = O(N)` elements so both reasonings seem valid but to me (1) seems correct

Comment: @Jim Binary search is O(logn) when time to access an element is O(1). The more correct way to put it would be time complexity of binary  search in O(logn * accesstime). `We aren't traversing N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8+... ` If the element lies in second half,  each iteration will take atleast N/2 time

Comment: @Jim Consider list `1 2 3 4 5 6`. To locate element `5`, We can narrow the range to `4 5 6` But time complexity is not N/2 since we have to iterate through `1 2 3` to reach the other elements

Comment: Yes but then it would be `O(N)` and not `O(NlogN)` right?

Comment: @Jim It would be O(n) to calculate the positions of beginning middle and end nodes and there would be log(n) iterations. So its n*log(n).